# What to do to make webapi's action secure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have made a webapi which has few actions and one is AddManualDate which accepts a parameter of the object type. It is consumed by Android devices. It works. But the problem is that the link is now exposed to the public and anyone can use it in a bad way. How to control it ?

my link for example:

```
http://www.testing.com/api/AndroidOperations/AddManualAppointment
```

now, this can be accessed by anyone. So what to do?

Comment: Sounds like you need to define an Authorization scheme and pass an Authorization header on your requests.  You app will have to validate each request based on the content of the header.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is using a token based authentication. Your client has to call the token api first, to get a token and pass it to every request against your api.

This is normally done by OWIN and OAuth. The following link describes the matter:
https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/06/11/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-2-via-owin/

Since this is a very general question, I can't give you a simple example.
Feel free to ask again if you get stuck in a detail. Happy coding!